# Is this json safe against XSS

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, xss

Hello I have been creating a sort function for a bunch of divs. For it to work I use the data atrribute of each div. To get the attributes into the div I have been using a javascript loop. I get the data from a php page where I have used  json_encode to return the data in the variable 'peoplelist' It looks like below (although could have 1000 records). I have stripped all characters except A-z and numbers  and replaced them with _ (this is for the sorting system to work properly)

```
[{
    "idnum": "100899801298",
    "firstname": "Lola",
    "surname": "Richards ",
    "sortcat1": "possibly bad infor",
    "sortcat2": "possibly bad data"
}, {
    "idnum": "102697973926",
    "firstname": "Lola",
    "surname": "Simonson",
    "sortcat1": "possibly bad infor",
    "sortcat2": "possibly bad data"
}, {
    "idnum": "154845984715",
    "firstname": "Simon",
    "surname": "Jones",
    "sortcat1": "possibly bad infor",
    "sortcat2": "possibly bad data"
}]
```

I had read that creating a variable and adding all the html to my div called "putdatahere" is more efficient(see below) however after reading a lot it seems this is open to XSS.

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "getdata.php",
cache: false,
success: function(peoplelist) {
    var peopleinfo = JSON.parse(peoplelist);
    var i,x="";
    for (i in peopleinfo) {
        var idnumstringed = pupilinfo[i].idnum.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var firstnamestringed = pupilinfo[i].firstname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var surnamestringed = pupilinfo[i].surname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var sortcat1stringed = pupilinfo[i].sortcat1.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var sortcat2stringed = pupilinfo[i].sortcat2.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var sortcat3stringed = pupilinfo[i].sortcat3.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var x+='<div id="pupdiv'+idnumstringed+'" data-firstname="'+firstnamestringed+'" data-surname="'+surnamestringed+'"  data-sortcat="'+sortcat1stringed+'" data-sortcat2="'+sortcat2stringed+'">'+firstname+' '+surname+'</div>';
    }
   $("#putdatahere").html(x);
   }
});
```

I had read that the only safe way to use unknown data is to put it in .text instead of .html. I don't know how to do this with the above method so I have now appended each div as we go along (see below)

```
 $.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "getdata.php",
cache: false,
success: function(peoplelist) {
    var peopleinfo = JSON.parse(peoplelist);
    var i,x="";
    for (i in peopleinfo) {
        var idnumstringed = pupilinfo[i].idnum.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var firstnamestringed = pupilinfo[i].firstname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var surnamestringed = pupilinfo[i].surname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var sortcat1stringed = pupilinfo[i].sortcat1.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var sortcat2stringed = pupilinfo[i].sortcat2.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');
        var sortcat3stringed = pupilinfo[i].sortcat3.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_');         
        $("#putdatahere").append('<div id="pupdiv'+idnumstringed+'" data-firstname="'+firstnamestringed+'" data-surname="'+surnamestringed+'"  data-sortcat="'+sortcat1stringed+'" data-sortcat2="'+sortcat2stringed+'"></div>');
        $("#pupdiv"+idnumstringed).text(firstname+' '+surname);     
    }
}
});
```

My questions are:

1) is the above append method safe from XSS or other attacks?

2) is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Insert text using .text and attributes via .attr and it will be safe. append bypasses those safety measures

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Can you give an example of how I would do this?

Comment: No, see the documentation.

Comment: What documentation? I want to be able to modify the data attribute and I've read that if I use .attr("data-something")  I can't so need to use .data(). Just looking for a way to understand your comment. Isn't that what this site is all about?

Comment: You asked for examples of using things I mentioned. The documentation has said examples, i see no need to repeat them. (they've also been repeated here thousands of times if you want to look, but documentation is far easier to find)

Comment: What documentation? Wouldn't it be easier to give an example or send a link to the documentation instead of telling me to read the documentation I don't know how to find. I thought this site was about helping others not acting high and mighty

Comment: It's jquery.... how can you not find the jquery documentation?

Comment: Thanks for being no help. Can anybody else actually show how to fix my code using  .attr so my data is safe and where the data attribute can be modfiied. You've said it's not safe but not shown how to fix it except saying read jquery documentation

Answer (score 0):

Removing all the non-alphanumeric characters should make it safe. But a better way is to create the element using jQuery's functional method rather than concatenating strings.

```
$("#putdatahere").append($("<div>", {
    id: "pupdiv" + idnum,
    data: { 
        firstname: pupilinfo[i].firstname,
        surname: pupilinfo[i].surname,
        sortcat: pupilinfo[i].sortcat1,
        sortcat2: pupilinfo[i].sortcat2,
        sortcat3: pupilinfo[i].sortcat3
    },
    text: pupilinfo[i].firstname + " " + pupilinfo[i].surname
}));
```

BTW, you forgot to put `sortcat3` in the element, and you left off `pupilinfo[i].` when calling `.text()`.

Comment: Awesome thanks. So if I use the method you showed above then XSS can't happen? Even if say pupilinfo[i].sortcat3 has some naughty code in it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. Nothing here will ever execute the data.